# pop up page , when a link button is clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

```
<td colspan ="2" style="width: 64px">
    <div style="float:left; padding-left:9px;">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkremoveloc" runat="server" 
            OnClick="lnkremoveloc_Click" CssClass="linkclass" 
            style="cursor:pointer" Font-Underline="True" 
            Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="12px">
            Remove Location
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
</td>
```

This is the link button from where i get a popup when clicked.
The popup page is like below. But when i click this link, the same page gets refreshed and i loose Save and Cancel button instead of opening a popup. Can someone help me out. I have no idea where i am doing wrong. Thanks a lot...

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="DisableLocation.aspx.cs" Inherits="DisableLocation" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<%--<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >--%>


<script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript" >

function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) {
    var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
    var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
    var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, 
            status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', 
            height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
} 

</script language ="javascript" type="text/javascript">


<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Disable Location | DealTown.com</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="display: block; background: url(images/reusable_blue_bg.jpg) repeat-x 0 -15px;border-left: #88b9c7 1px solid; border-bottom:#88b9c7 1px solid; border-top:#88b9c7 1px solid; border-right: #88b9c7 1px solid;   padding: 0px 2px;   height: 236px;  min-height: 236px;  height: auto;   margin-left: auto;  margin-right: auto;">
        <table align="center" style="width: 554px; border-top-style: none;  border-right-style: none;
            border-left-style: none; border-bottom-style: none" id="TABLE1">
            <tr >
                <td align="center" colspan="5" style="font-weight:normal;font-size:18px;margin: 0px;font-family: Arial;color: #1e7c9b;" >Disable Location</td>
            </tr>

            <asp:GridView ID="diableloc" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
             DataKeyNames="LocationName" DataSourceID="getGridMerchantLocationData" 
             AllowPaging="True" EnableViewState="False">
             <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="chkbox" HeaderText="Select" 
                SortExpression="Selection" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="locname" HeaderText="Location Name" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Locnames" />
            </Columns>
           </asp:GridView>

           <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ProductsDataSource" runat="server" 
           OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
           SelectMethod="GetLocations" TypeName="string">            
           </asp:ObjectDataSource>


            </table>
              <tr>
                <td style="width: 44px; height: 63px">
                </td>
                <td style="width: 127px; height: 63px">
                </td>
                <td align="left" colspan="2" style="height: 63px; width: 196px;">
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDisable" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/save.gif" OnClick="btnDisable_Click"
                 ValidationGroup="group1" />
                 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCancel" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel.gif" OnClick="btnCancel_Click" /></td>
                <td colspan="1" style="width: 92px; height: 63px">
                </td>
            </tr> 

        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the page is posting back.  Did you try `AutoPostBack="false"`?  Not sure you need a LinkButton here.  Can you just use a anchor tag with `onclick` instead to invoke the popup?

Do you have code that needs to execute on the server side when the LinkButton is clicked?  If you need both you can use the OnClientClick property to have both.  *It has been a while, but I think you can make it so the server code won't execute if the value returned from the client side code in onclientclick returns false.*

I don't see how your current LinkButton shows the popup.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `OnClick` use `OnClientClick="lnkremoveloc_Click"` where lnkremoveloc_Click is JavaScript function (somthing like PopupCenter you already have) that opens popup window.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `onclientclick` instead of `onclick`. And while rendering(page load) itself set the `onclientclick` as `"PopupCenter('url','title',....);return false;"`

The url, title, width, etc can be set on load. The last part "return false" will annul the effect of click. Thus it prevents post back.

Note: If you want something to be processed at server side, its better not to set the `onclientclick` and use 
`Response.write("<script>PopupCenter('url','title',....);</script>");`

I hope that helps.

This is my first post :)